# Circle ImageView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

**UPDATE 12/29/15**
So this apparently worked in `UICollectionViewCell` class:

```
- (void)setThumbnailImage:(NSString *)thumbnailImage {
   _thumbnailImage = [thumbnailImage copy];


   self.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:thumbnailImage];
   if (self.thumbnailImageView.layer.frame.size.width > 82.0f) {
    self.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width/6;
   }
   else {
    self.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width/2;
   }
   self.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   self.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
   self.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;
}
```

I do not know why the ImageView frame updates after refresh instead of when it first loads. Can someone please elaborate?

**Problem**

I'm struggling trying to get the correct frame size of an ImageView so that I can make it a circle instead of a square.

In `UICollectionViewController`, I have in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` the code to make an ImageView circle `cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width/2;`.

The problem is that the ImageView is diamond like because the frame size is not correct but when I scroll up and down, the cells that are refreshed are circle and have the correct frame size it's suppose to have made in the storyboard.

[Here is the refreshed CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hCf1.png)

Here is a snippet of my code in `UICollectionViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self setupDKScrollingView];

names = @[@"Joe Smith", @"Veronica Odel", @"Lucas Baze", @"Brian Can", @"Cory Cobler", @"Emily Jenson"];
timeRemaining = @[@"Overdue", @"0 days", @"Past", @"1 month", @"2 days", @"4 days"];
thumbnails = @[@"gray_1",@"gray_1",@"gray_1",@"gray_1",@"gray_1",@"gray_1"];

[self.collectionView reloadData]; 
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return [names count];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 1;
 }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

RZEContactsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ContactCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//cell.nameLabel.text = names[indexPath.row];
//cell.timeRemainingLabel.text = timeRemaining[indexPath.row];
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:thumbnails[image.row]];
cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width/2;
cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: The height and width of ImageView is same?

Comment: In the storyboard with constraints, yes. It gives me the default size when I try to NSLog. Default size is (120, 240), I believe.

Comment: Means height and width are not same. width is 120 and height is 240. Try to keep both height and width same and try again.

Comment: I did in the storyboard. The storyboard constraints are 82x82. But when I NSLog the frame, it gives me 120x240 but when I scroll up and down, reloading the cells, it gives me the correct size which is 82x82.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: resize image with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` when u load it

Comment: @aaisataev in which method?

Comment: r u getting image from internet?

Comment: @aaisataev No, it's a screenshot

Comment: then before `cell.imageview.image`

Comment: @MehulSojitra edited post

Comment: @aaisataev It did not work

Comment: TIP: do your drawings by overriding drawRect method of your tableview/collectionview cell.

Comment: I am assuming changing value 2.0 worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.collectionImgView.clipsToBounds=YES;
cell.collectionImgView.layer.cornerRadius=cell.collectionImgView.frame.size.width/2;
cell.collectionImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_photosArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not get perfect circle in every device, try changing **2.0** to different near by values for different size devices.

```
{   
cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width/2.0;
cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```